# Safari's KeyboardEvent is so weird

Tags: javascript, safari, keyboard-events

jsfriddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gLv101mr/ (visit it with safari)

html:

```
<input type='text' id='text'/>
```

js:

```
$('#text').on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.type, e.which)
  e.preventDefault()
  return false
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log(e.type, e.which)
  e.preventDefault()
  return false
}).on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log(e.type, e.which)
  e.preventDefault()
  return false
})
```

When press alphabet keys(include enter, backspace, <>, etc..) , the keyboard event is correctly prevented, user cannot input anything. But the digit keys still can input(include +-@#$ and space key)!

And when press digit keys, keydown event's keyCode prop is always 229, you can't determine which key pressed.

It's a nightmare, I remembered that this situation occurred once before, what should I do to handle keyboard events in Safari browser??

Comment: try use a fake input to show, and  a hidden input to keep real value, this is not a prefect solution if u don't have better one

Comment: Just to be sure, which safari are you talking about?

Comment: Mac 9.1.2 (11601.7.7)

Comment: Hmm can't repro on mine...

Comment: @Kaiido So what is your Safari version and platform?

Comment: 9.1.2 (9537.86.7.7) (osx 10.9)